# оптимизация тригонометрических функций через предварительное генерирование словаря?

Tags: python

пытаюсь ускорить выполнение базовых тригонометрических функций.
пока вывел только на 125%
советы и примеры по оптимизации?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import timeit
import math
dbg = 1
def frange(start, stop, ndigt=1):
    ''' создание range с возможностью использовать float в шаге '''
    r = float(start)
    ret = []
    st = float(stop)+round(1./10**ndigt,ndigt)
    if start < stop:
        while r <= st:
            r1 = round(r,ndigt)
            ret.append(r1)
            r += round(1./10**ndigt,ndigt)
        return ret


def prepare_trigon(pcos, psin, ptan, ndig=4):
    ''' подготовка предварительно просчитанных значений sin cos tan
        для предотвращения перерасчетов
        ndig <- количество знаков после запятой'''

    if dbg: print "подготовка тригонометрических функций (sin,cos,tan) с глубиной ", ndig
    trig_range = frange(-math.pi, math.pi, ndig)  # todo подобрать значение десятичной
    for i in trig_range:
        pcos[i]= math.cos(i)
        psin[i]= math.sin(i)
        ptan[i]= math.tan(i)


start = timeit.default_timer()
pcos, psin, ptan = {}, {}, {},
prepare_trigon(pcos, psin, ptan, 4)
t =  (timeit.default_timer() - start )
print 'Подготовка заняла ', t
it = 1000000
tm = 0.2345
d = 4
start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(it):
    a = math.cos(tm)
    b = math.sin(tm)
    c = math.tan(tm)

t1 =  (timeit.default_timer() - start )
print '\nВычисление ',it," операций MATH заняло - ", t1

start = timeit.default_timer()
for i in range(it):
    b = pcos[tm]
    b = psin[tm]
    b = ptan[tm]
t2 = (timeit.default_timer() - start )
print 'Вычисление ',it," операций PREP заняло - ", t2
print '\nОтношение скорости = ', round(t1/t2,4)*100,"%"
```

Comment: Бессмысленно. Перепешите на C - будет быстрее.

Comment: вообще то весь модуль math в python написан на C

Comment: Было бы очень полезно узнать немного больше о __реальной__ задаче.  Тогда сообщество SO могло бы дать более дельные советы. Пока непонятно зачем считать тригоном-е функции для __одних и тех же занчений__ 1.000.000 раз...

Comment: Непонятно о чём вопрос. Что вы хотите ускорить? Насколько? Какой контекст? Какие входные данные? Сколько их? Какой диапазон входных значений? Как вывод используется? Какая точность нужна? Подходят ли GPU решения? В тему: [How does C compute sin() and other math functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2284860/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/):

```
In [73]: %%timeit
    ...: pcos, psin, ptan = {}, {}, {},
    ...: prepare_trigon(pcos, psin, ptan, 4)
    ...:
подготовка тригонометрических функций (sin,cos,tan) с глубиной  4
подготовка тригонометрических функций (sin,cos,tan) с глубиной  4
подготовка тригонометрических функций (sin,cos,tan) с глубиной  4
подготовка тригонометрических функций (sin,cos,tan) с глубиной  4
1 loop, best of 3: 237 ms per loop
```

---

```
In [74]: import numpy as np

In [75]: %%timeit
    ...: args = np.arange(-math.pi, math.pi, .0001).round(4)
    ...: pcos, psin, ptan = np.cos(args), np.sin(args), np.tan(args)
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ms per loop
```

или [Numexpr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr):

```
In [79]: import numexpr as ne

In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: args = np.arange(-math.pi, math.pi, .0001).round(4)
    ...: pcos, psin, ptan = ne.evaluate("cos(args)"), ne.evaluate("sin(args)"), ne.evaluate("tan(args)")
    ...:
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых никаких 125% тут нет. Вывод вашего скрипта

```
Вычисление  1000000  операций MATH заняло -  0.494678974152
Вычисление  1000000  операций PREP заняло -  0.408390045166
```

Разница в 19%.

Во вторых непонятно что именно вы хотите посчитать? Сколько займет миллион обращений к элементу словаря, и сколько займет миллион раз вычислить синус одного и того же числа? Почитайте про кеширование в процессорах.

В третьих после простейших преобразований (судя по всему вы используете python 2.X)

```
from math import cos, sin, tan, pi
...
for i in xrange(it):
    a = cos(tm)
    b = sin(tm)
    c = tan(tm)
...
for i in xrange(it):
    b = pcos[tm]
    b = psin[tm]
    b = ptan[tm]
```

получаем следующий результат

```
Вычисление  1000000  операций MATH заняло -  0.371814012527
Вычисление  1000000  операций PREP заняло -  0.391256093979
```

О ужас - оказывается тут не ускорение, а замедление! Почему так?

Потому что весь модуль math в python - это обертка над С функциями, а они в свою очередь написаны достаточно эффективно (и расчитанные заранее таблицы там тоже есть). Со словарем все тоже не так однозначно - во время вставки большого количества элементов происходят коллизии, и получение элемента словаря становится медленнее. Про устройство словаря почитать [можно тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/247843/)

```
In [28]: d = {1:2}
In [29]: %timeit d[1]
10000000 loops, best of 3: 62.6 ns per loop

In [42]: len(psin)
Out[42]: 62833

In [43]: %timeit psin[val]
The slowest run took 19.62 times longer than the fastest. This could      mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 122 ns per loop
```

Тут уже посоветовали использовать numpy, но стоит учесть, что numpy лучше не использовать для скалярных вычислений.

```
In [51]: from numpy import sin

In [52]: %timeit sin(0.5)
The slowest run took 16.19 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 794 ns per loop

In [53]: from math import sin

In [54]: %timeit sin(0.5)
The slowest run took 23.83 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 81.7 ns per loop
```

Ну и непонятно зачем вам вообще ускорять тригонометрические методы - в каком таком алгоритме скорость работы упирается в вычисление синуса?

Comment: попробуйте замерить скорость вычисления тригонометрической функции для, скажем, 10.000 елементов списка и сделать тоже самое в Numpy... ;-)

Comment: цитирую сам себя: 'Тут уже посоветовали использовать numpy, но стоит учесть, что numpy лучше не использовать для скалярных вычислений.' Про векторные вычисления я ничего не говорил =)